# Redirect all pages to https except index using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all pages to `https` except from the index page. that means: `/` or `index` or `index.php`.

In addition, if someone entered the index page with `https`, it'll redirect him to `http`.

How can I do that?

Thank you, and sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^(index(\.php)?)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks! and if someone else will want to do it: I also added in the `private_html` the opposite of this code, so it'll redirect from https to http in the index.